# Project will not build

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So it took me a while to find a codeblock with a compiler but in the end I found one... I wrote a very simple code (learning)

```
//
//  Conversion - Program to convert temperature from Celsius degrees to      
    Fahrenheit : Fahrenheit = Celsius * (212 - 32)/100 + 32
//
//
//
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
// enter the temperature in Celsius
int celsius;
cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius:";
cin >> celsius;

// calculate conversion factor for Celsius
// to Fahrenheit
int factor;
factor = 212 - 32;

// use conversion factor to convert Celsius
// into Fahrenheit values
int fahrenheit;
fahrenheit = factor * celsius/100 + 32;

// output the results (followed by a NewLine)
cout << "Fahrenheit value is:";
cout << fahrenheit << endl;

// wait until user is ready before terminating program
// to allow the user to see the program results
cout << "Press Enter to continue..." << endl;
cin.ignore(10, '/n');
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

but I keep getting this error

-------------- Build: Debug in Conversion (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Conversion.exe obj\Debug\main.o
Execution of 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Conversion.exe obj\Debug\main.o' in 'C:\CPP_Programs_from_Book\Conversion' failed.

will not build

ps im using code::blocks
PLZ how do I fix this

Comment: You should post the actual error message. Before you do that, you should read the error message yourself, it will give you the line number and explain the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a comment has been left uncommented.

```
//
//  Conversion - Program to convert temperature from Celsius degrees to      
    Fahrenheit : Fahrenheit = Celsius * (212 - 32)/100 + 32
//
```

Should be

```
//
//  Conversion - Program to convert temperature from Celsius degrees to      
//  Fahrenheit : Fahrenheit = Celsius * (212 - 32)/100 + 32
//
```

Comment: Sorry the copy and paste was a bit off. That line in my code is one line